# will a jms call in finally block in servlet affect perfomance

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, jms

will a jms call in a finally block of a doPost will affect the perfomance..the response is written in try block and flushed. After that in finally a jms call is being made..whether response will be delivered before jms call?

Answer (score 0):

> whether response will be delivered before jms call?

Until `finally` blobk is executed, the control doesn't return from method.

But, it's depends on may criterias that what will happen first, such as:

1. Network traffic
2. System performance
3. OS scheduling (may be)
4. ...

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether the Servlet container is buffering the response. It usually does, so it can evaluate Content-Length and set that response header for you. But anything called in a finally block generally *must* be called, so worrying about its performance or timeliness is completely irrelevant. You don't have the choice.